# How to tell map function of the MapperModel that specific filed should have specific value?

Tags: java, spring, mapping, modelmapper

I use ModelMapper in my project to map between DTO classes and models.

For example:

```
public class UserDto {
    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private String email;
}

 
public class User {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String metaDatal;
    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private String email;
}
```

Here How I map it:

```
@Autowired
private ModelMapper modelMapper;
modelMapper.map(userDto, user);
```

As you can see I have metaDatal field in the user model, I want to set this field with a specific value.

Specific field(metaDatal) of the mapped class I want to set this value "abc123".
Is there any way to tell map method when it called that, specific filed(for example metaData) should have specific value(for example abc123)?

Comment: Initialise the `metaData` field to the value you want. (and skip the field `typeMap.addMappings(mapper -> mapper.skip(User::setMetaDatal));`)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the most flexible way to do this is to implement a simple `Converter`. Check this:

```
Converter<UserDto, User> metaData = new Converter<UserDto, User>() {
    // This is needed to convert as usual but not having not registered
    // this converter to avoid recursion
    private final ModelMapper mm = new ModelMapper();
    @Override
    public User convert(MappingContext<UserDto, User> context) {
        User u = context.getDestination();
        mm.map(context.getSource(), u);
        u.setMetaDatal("abc123");
        return context.getDestination();
    }
};
```

Now it is just to create a `TypeMap` and set this converter to handle conversion, like:

```
modelMapper.createTypeMap(UserDto.class, User.class).setConverter(metaData);
```

before `modelMapper.map()`.

You could also add a getter for metadata in your `UserDto`, like:

```
public String getMetaDatal() {
    return "abc123";
}
```

If it is something that can be derived from `UserDto` directly and skip the converter part.